# Send mail from PHP with minimum 3rd party services?

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

Dont ignore if this sounds like a duplicate. I went through similar questions here but couldnt resolve my doubts.

Im developing a site in my localhost. Its coded in PHP. I need to send mail to my site's customers from my PHP script. I know we can use gmail smtp server for this. But due to the limit on the mail/day set by google, i prefer not to use them.

But my doubts are:

1. Can i do it without gmail's smtp server or anyone else's smtp server?
2. What all components would i need to send mails from my localhost as well as from my online webserver?
3. Does all the webservers come pre-configured to enable us to send mail from site?
4. What is sendMail, phpMailer, pearMail etc.? I've been advised to use them. But what are they?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Im using wamp2.2 in my localhost.

Comment: 1. yes if there is a local smtp server defined on your hosting, 2. a smtp server on your localhost as well as one on your hosting, 3. no, depends on host policy and service you subscribed to, 4. Just shorthands libs to avoid creating a mail all by yourself ...

Comment: @yent, what SMTP server(free versions) can i use on localhost and webserver? Any suggestions?

Comment: There's lots, but sending mail from your local computer will most likely fail as (as KingCrush mentionned) you won't have MX/SPF records so the recipients MTA will flag it as spam ...

Comment: Can you suggest one free version please. I'll be sending mail from my Personal Computer(localhost) only for testing purpose. Once its working i intend to host my site and then onwards mails will be sent from my domain.

Comment: You can try Postmark, the url is http://www.postmarkapp.com. It's not free but you'll get 1000 free email credits after registration. Integrating it is very easy. :)

Comment: Sure but either your internet provider or your recipient mailbox host will forbid you to send mail from your personal computer and no package will allow you to change that ... One way to do things would be to use a helper class (pearMailer maybe ?) that will be able to use a remote smtp when on localhost and that you will configure to use the local smtp once hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course
2. Setup an own MTA (Mail Transport Agent) like postfix.
3. In my experience the shared hosts usually already offers a mail agent. If you really mean "webserver", than no: A webserver is a webserver. Preconfigured packages like XAMPP usually also comes with a MTA.
4. Libraries to send mail. `sendMail` could be `sendmail`, which is itself a MTA-interface.

Comment: Thanks KingCrunch. So in short, i'll only need an MTA(like postfix) to send mail from localhost, right?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I didn't realize, that you want to send the mails from your personal computer. In this case your mails will very probably be marked as spam, if you don't have a domain with the corresponding `MX`records defined in a public nameserver.

Comment: I'll be sending mail from my Personal Computer(localhost) only for testing purpose. Once its working i intend to host my site and then onwards mails will be sent from my domain.

Comment: For development and/or testing I recommend either don't send mails at all (e.g. Swiftmailer allows to safe mails as text files instead of sending them), or keep with gmail.

Answer (score 2):

If you use XAMPP, it comes with Mercury Mail. You can use that to send mails through localhost.

Comment: Im using wamp 2.2. Does it that same feature?

Comment: I'm not sure if WAMP comes with inbuilt Mercury mail, but this should help you http://www.satyamtechnologies.net/articles/how-to-configure-mercury-mail-server-on-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

to send email from php , simply use php's own mail function :

```
 <?php

             $to = "destinationemailid";

             $subject = "mail subject";

             $message = "your message to send";

             $from =  "sourceemailid";

             $headers = "From:" . $from;

             mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);



        ?>
```

this works with xampp on localhost